# How to unzip a directory inside a zip file

Tags: directory, zip

I want to unzip a certail directory inside a zip file using the following command:

```
unzip -oq vqmodmanager.zip upload -d temp/
```

But the system gives the following error:

```
caution: filename not matched:  upload
```

Actually, there is a directory called `upload` inside the zip file.

How can I unzip that directory only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try do append / to the directory name just as:

```
unzip -oq vqmodmanager.zip upload/ -d temp/
```

Comment: you might need to specify `upload/*`