# Unzip indoes only of a particular tier/level of a zip file, with unzip

Tags: zip

I use this command to extract a zip file containing a backup of my document root:

```
unzip /var/www/html/html-2018-01-08-02\:52\:11.zip -d /var/www/html/
```

This extracts all data inside the document root, but there's a problem, the current state is a duplicated document root:

```
/var/www/html/var/www/html/DATA
```

Of course I can move the data back with `mv` and then delete the duplicated document root with `cd /var/www/html && rm -rf /var/www/html`, but the most minimal solution would be to achieve that directly form `unzip`.

I aspire that the duplication won't happen in the first place.

---

How to unzip indoes only of a particular tier/level of a zip file, with `unzip`?

For example, my zip includes:

- First tier: `/var`.
- Second tier: `/var/www`.
- Third tier: `/var/www/html/`.

I want to extract only the inodes of the forth tier (tier 3, in zero-based index, of course).

The end state should be:

```
/var/www/html/DATA
```

Comment: In the end I used `unzip ${drt}/all_zipped*    &&    mv ${drt}/${drt}/* ${drt}/    &&    rm -rf ${drt}/${drt}/` while `${drt}` is my document root.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unzip a directory inside a zip file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57799/how-to-unzip-a-directory-inside-a-zip-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit `unzip` to the files you want to extract, by path:

With wildcards:

```
unzip foo.zip '*/*/*/*'
```

With literal syntax:

```
unzip foo.zip 'var/www/html/*'
```

For example:

```
$ zipinfo ../1.zip 
Archive:  ../1.zip
Zip file size: 1134 bytes, number of entries: 8
drwxrwxr-x  3.0 unx        0 bx stor 18-Jan-28 13:53 1/
drwxrwxr-x  3.0 unx        0 bx stor 18-Jan-28 13:53 1/2/
drwxrwxr-x  3.0 unx        0 bx stor 18-Jan-28 13:53 1/2/3/
drwxrwxr-x  3.0 unx        0 bx stor 18-Jan-28 13:53 1/2/3/4/
-rw-rw-r--  3.0 unx        0 bx stor 18-Jan-28 13:53 1/2/3/4/d
-rw-rw-r--  3.0 unx        0 bx stor 18-Jan-28 13:53 1/2/3/c
-rw-rw-r--  3.0 unx        0 bx stor 18-Jan-28 13:53 1/2/b
-rw-rw-r--  3.0 unx        0 bx stor 18-Jan-28 13:53 1/a
8 files, 0 bytes uncompressed, 0 bytes compressed:  0.0%
$  unzip ../1.zip '*/*/*/*'
Archive:  ../1.zip
   creating: 1/2/3/
   creating: 1/2/3/4/
 extracting: 1/2/3/4/d               
 extracting: 1/2/3/c
```

Comment: In the end I used `unzip ${drt}/all_zipped*    &&    mv ${drt}/${drt}/* ${drt}/    &&    rm -rf ${drt}/${drt}/` while `${drt}` is my document root.